# how to stop elements from stacking? jqueryui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BAk9N/4/

I'm trying to make it so "test' elements can not drag on top of other test elements and stack and have not found a working solution.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent test elements from stacking on each other?

Thank you.

Comment: You just don't want them to be dropped on top of the other 'test' elements or you don't want them to be able to even hover (while dragging) over the other 'test' elements?

Comment: I meant the first one, but I would be happy with the second one as well.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I can see is the reason the snapping is acting so funny is the margins between  your li's.  If you take off the `//margin: 10px;` from the `.meals li` css than it snaps to the middle of the element.  I would recommend taking that off.  Otherwise I feel like you're going to have to come up with your own snapping solution.

Also this is a fiddle I made for a person with another question semi-similar to this.  This may help you out in a custom snapping solution.

Demo here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeschafe/JTKBR/)