# How to stop jquery ui draggle / droppable elements from stacking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BAk9N/4/

I would like it so "test" elements are unable to stack on top of each other.

Either the element should just return where it came from, or the mouse should be unable to move on top of the other test element.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and am unable to come up with a solution.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You just asked [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873513/how-to-stop-elements-from-stacking-jqueryui) yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition function in your accept for droppable accept:

```
   `$( ".draggable-snap" ).droppable({
    accept: function(){
                /* Insert code here */ 
    },...`
```

For example, to test whether there is any Menu's snapped to it at the moment.

See this for help:
http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-drag-drop-lock